# What's Photoshop CS6 keyboard shortcut to call Edit - Transform - Scale?

Tags: macos, keyboard, adobe-photoshop

I'm not able to see any predefined keyboard shortcut to call Scale under Transform.

[image]

If such a shortcut does not exist, is there any possibility to define one, so a specific thing will be called?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use the shortcut for `Free transform`?

Either way...

You can edit / add keyboard shortcuts in Photoshop in: 
`Edit > Keyboard shortcuts...`

[image]